# Iterate & print values in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I just have started ember.js. My markup code is

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
        <h1>Names: </h1>
        {{#each home in App.HomeController.content}}
                <h1>Name: </h1>
                {{home.name}}<br />            
        {{/each}}
</script>
```

and my javascript code is

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("home", {
        path: "/"
    });   
});

/*
 *  HomeController
 */
App.HomeController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [],
    templateName: 'home',
    init: function(){
        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'response.php',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',            
            success: function(res){                
                self.set('content', res);                
            },
            error: function(){                

            }
        });

    }    

})
```

But it seems that i can not print name. I cannot iterate & print the name. Can any body help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to provide `controller`, never a full path (`App.HomeController.content`):

```
{{#each home in controller}}
  <h1>Name: </h1>
  {{home.name}}<br />            
{{/each}}
```

The reasons for this:

- When you write `Ember.ArrayController.extend()`, you create a *class*, not an *instance*. Ember will automatically create the instances for you.
- The `controller` variable in a given template points to the controller of the same name as the template. In your case:

  1. Template name: `home`
  2. Controller: instance of `App.HomeController`

Also, there is no need to point to an `ArrayController`'s `content`, as it's only a proxy , hence it is the default context for iterations.